# Runtime permissions from ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, runtime-permissions

The `listview` has few image views and few buttons in each row.
Showing the `listview` images do not require any permissions, however, on any button click I need to request runtime permissions.

Since runtime permissions callback method can only be accessed from the activity, how do I ensure that if the permissions are granted listview button click goes on as intended.

I have read other answers which suggests asking for permissions when the listview is rendered however I  cannot do that.

Comment: Better to write your code, whatever you have did so for. So one can figure out issues.

Comment: ask permission before setting your adapter if all permission granted then only set your adapter

Comment: Add interface to your listview adapter. Call that interface on your button's click. Than implement that interface to your activity.